How read NFC card with external Reader for android phone
Facing a problem with the reader R20XC. It is connected with mobile and red light is glowing, indicate the reader is on, but the card is not reading.
Solution to read NFC card with R20XC.Also Suggest a mobile app to read data from R20XC.

Your question is not clear; please clarify your question, and add more details. Follow this about how to ask question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

My be driver issues for NFC card

Solution, unless the manufacturer provides an Android App then you will have to write an Android App yourself.
Android will only see it as a generic USB device, all Android's NFC stuff only works with built in hardware readers.
So your App will have to be written to send specific data (which can be got from the readers Datasheet) to the USB port for it to read anything.
